# Step by step process for setting up Gallio and NbUnit within TeamCity

Tags: teamcity, gallio

I have searched the internet and found a few references saying that Gallio and NbUnit can run within TeamCity as part of the build process.

I am running my builds against the solutions files and need TeamCity to run all the test in the solution.

Is there a step by step process for setting up Gallio and NbUnit within TeamCity anywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this through MSBuild

```
      <!-- Runs Tests -->
      <Gallio IgnoreFailures="true" Files="@(TestFiles)">
        <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" PropertyName="ExitCode" />
      </Gallio>
      <Error Text="Tests execution failed" Condition=" '$(ExitCode)' != 0 And '@(TestFiles)' != '' " />
```

Comment: I would not call this step by step :/ Please provide more information. Where should I put this xml?